# MYSQL Group By Query with subtract of number based on where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i have One transaction table ( "TableA" ), In TableA have those fields **app_id, user_id, points, tr_type, description**. so in the transaction have added and subtract tr_type is there. now I want to get total_points (points = added-subtract) of the user_id based on tr_type. For that how I need to write MySQL query>

For type is either add or sub.

So now I want GroupBY of those 3 fields --> **app_id, user_id, points**

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired rsults.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id,
       sum(case when tr_type = 'add' then points 
                when tr_type = 'sub' then - points
           end)
from t
group by user_id;
```

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, it's working fine, thanks

Comment: Do we have any possibility to update/Replace those points on another MySQL table?

Comment: @Venkatasivaramireddy.Venna . . . That would be a different question.  Of course, you can use a query like this in an `update` or `insert`.